# Tablix Grouping Keep Together

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I know this has been asked, but I just can't get a solution to my problem.

I have a report with a graph in a tablix and the first line as the graph header, this is in turn grouped by values to repeat the graph for each value in the group. All works well, until the report starts a new page causing the header to remain on one page and the graph on the next.

I tried the following.

1. Keep Together on one page if possible in the Properties of the Tablix
2. Repeat rows on each page (Even though this is not actually what I require)
3. Column Groups Advanced Mode > Row Groups > Static Lines as well as the Group I have set the properties to: Keep Together, Keep With Group and Tried Both Before and After)
4. Playing around with the Page size
5. I have also tried, screaming, holding my head and a lot of swearing

But it still prints as per the pictures and driving me mad, I have spend more time trying to sort out the formatting than writing the SQL Stored Procs.[image: Page 1][image: Page 2][image: Design]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: did you try Column Groups Advanced Mode > Row Groups > Static Lines > RepeatOnNewPage True + KeepWithGroup True. Also did you try sacrifice an intern to microsoft?

Comment: I tried that now... didn't work, the intern option seems to be the only option now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the graph size to fit exactly on the page.

This works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two potential solutions here:

First would be to split the tablix cell that is currently holding your chart into two rows, putting your chart in lower one and the title in the upper one.  As these two cells will be a part of one tablix row, they *should* stay together.  If this works I would personally prefer it as it is easier to manage layout-wise.

Second would be to have just the one cell for chart and title.  [Start by adding a rectangle to your tablix cell](https://simplesqlserver.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/ssrs-add-objects-to-a-tablix-cell/), which will let you place multiple report items within the cell with a layout of your choosing.  Add in a textbox formatted per your current title cell above your chart and as they are within the same tablix cell they will definitely stay together on the same row.

Comment: Thank you I am sure this will work, I was a bit out of time and got it to work by resizing the graphs to fit on a page. I am sure to try these options.